# Another MoebiusMu question

Tags: number-theory

When I evaluate the Mertens function to infinity:

```
NSum[MoebiusMu[k], {k, 1, \[Infinity]}]
```

I get -1, but I expected to get -2.

I wanted to modify the function thus:

```
Unprotect[MoebiusMu];  
MoebiusMu[1] := -1  
Protect[MoebiusMu];
```

in order to get -2.  But that gives me -3.

So, why does `NSum` return -1.?

Comment: If `MoebiusMu[1]` is changed from `1` to `-1`, I would expect the sum to decrease by `2`.  To get it to decrease by `1`, you might change `MoebiusMu[1]` to `0` or consider just subtracting `1` from the sum.

Comment: You probably have a good reason for wanting to change the system function, but it does destroy its multiplicativity property.  If there are internal rules that rely on the property, I would worry that errors might be introduced.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think the problem isn't along that line. The Mertens function oscillates badly http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_conjecture

Comment: @MichaelE2, it is along that line. I am trying to use analytic continuation in the non-negative reals to define Mertens at $s=0$.  Because _Mathematica_ returns -1., I can change to a zero. But I need to know where the -1. comes from so I can explain it.  I am working on a question for mathMO which I should post soon, in which I will explain my reasoning. I'll post a link here when that happens.

Comment: @FredKline I see.  I misunderstood.

Comment: Well, $\mu$ falls under number theory, and I'd think, well, [tag:number-theory] is slightly more useful here than [tag:functions]. Anyway...

Comment: I see four close votes. I vote **against** closing, myself.

Comment: I'm one of the close votes -- I voted when I misunderstood the question, but SE doesn't ley you unvote.  I'll vote to reopen if it closes.

Comment: @MichaelE2, these are the first close votes I have received on this forum. I get them regularly on math.SE and MO, usually for ill-formed questions. However, I did get a fine answer, which was my goal, so I'm fine with everything.

Comment: @MichaelE2, In working-up the question for MO, I have realized that $\mu(\cdot)$ is not the issue. Mertens with $s=0$ is the issue. So, I might not be linking to this question anyway.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I did not link to this question, but here is a link to MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/130285/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short `NSum` cannot handle this sort of sequence.  Indeed, strictly the series is not convergent, and some notion of summability/regularization needs to be chosen.
Given the nature of `MoebiusMu`, `"Dirichlet"` seems appropriate:

```
Sum[MoebiusMu[k], {k, 1, \[Infinity]}, Regularization -> "Dirichlet"]
  (* -2 *)
```

---

Here's how one can see `NSum` is not working reliably.
From the [`NSum` reference page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NSum.html):

> You should realize that with sufficiently pathological summands, the algorithms used by NSum can give wrong answers. In most cases, you can test the answer by looking at its sensitivity to changes in the setting of options for NSum.

The default for `NSumTerms` is `15`.  Here's what happens if we increase that:

```
Quiet@NSum[MoebiusMu[k], {k, 1, \[Infinity]}, NSumTerms -> #] & /@  Range[15, 30]

(* {-1., -1., -1., ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, -4., -4.,
    ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, -1., -1., -1.5, ComplexInfinity,
    0., 0., ComplexInfinity} *)
```

You get all sorts of answers.  `Quiet` is suppressing the warning

> ```
> NSum::nsumz: Some terms are zero. The algorithms are not very applicable. >>
> ```

One can see which terms are being tested this way:

```
ListPlot[Reap[NSum[MoebiusMu[k], {k, 1, Infinity}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[k]]][[2, 1]]]
```

[image: Sample Points]

The [`NSum` reference page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NSum.html)
suggests this is typical of the sequence extrapolation method.  `MoebiusMu` is not well-suited for extrapolation from these points.

Comment: +1, very nice. Since I am applying the analysis to only the $s=0$ situation, I can define MoebiusMu as I see fit (assuming I can prove it.)

Comment: On the other hand, if we take the [well-known identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/NumberTheoryFunctions/MoebiusMu/23/02/0003/) $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(k)}{k^s}=\frac1{\zeta(s)}$$ and take $s\to1$, we get $0$...

Comment: @J.M.  Did you mean $s \rightarrow 0$?  That's what *Mathematica* is doing with [`Regularization -> "Dirichlet"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Regularization.html).  And the result is $1/\zeta(0) = -2$.

Comment: @Michael, oops, you're right.